# Understanding how summation changes to vector

Tags: summation, vectors

In my research work I came across the following two equations:

$y(t) = \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n b_n\right)x(t)$ ---(1)

$y(t) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}x(t)$ ---(2)

where $\mathbf{A} = [a_1,a_2,...,a_N]$ and $\mathbf{B} = [b_1,b_2,...,b_N]^T$.

My query is how summation in equation (1) change to vector in eq (2).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, if you have a $m\times n$ matrix and a $n\times k$ matrix, then their product is a $m\times k$ matrix. Here, $\textbf{A}$ is a $1\times N$ matrix and $\textbf{B}$ is an $N\times1$ matrix, so the product $\textbf{AB}$ is a $1\times1$ matrix, which is just a fancy term for a scalar in this case. Were you to actually perform the multiplication, you would find that you get exactly the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_nb_n$; times a factor of $x(t)$ and you recover equation 1. Another way of looking at it is that, by definition, the product of vectors $<a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_N>$ and $<b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_N>^T$ is the dot product of the two vectors, which is always a scalar quantity. Long story short, there are no actual vectors here; the notation $\textbf{AB}$, as a dot product, is merely a shorthand for the original summation notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your response...I would say one word "AWSOME" for your explanation...

Comment: You are very welcome! Please don't hesitate to tag me in any future questions; I'm always keen to help if I can :)